# Fixing the spacing on last row when browser window is expanded

Tags: html, css

edit: Resolved: See Mr. Lister's answer.

The last row seems to lose its horizontal spacing when the browser window is stretched wider than about 1000px. 
Note specifically that on the final row of the screenshot below, the horizontal spacing between elements is smaller than on the rows above it.

Example: http://opinnacle.ca/galleria.html

How can I resolve this?

[image: screenshot of the spacing issue]

The source used in this example is shown below:

HTML:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; width: 100%; padding-top: 65px; background: #eee; min-height:100%;">
    <div style="min-width:300px; height: 100%; padding-top:5px;"></div>
    <ul style="text-align:justify; margin:0 auto; width:100%;">
        <li class="roundcontainer"><img src="images/image1.png" alt="#" /> <div class="icononame">Aaton Boards</div></li>
        <li class="roundcontainer"><img src="images/image2.png" alt="#" /><div class    ="icononame">Ascento</div></li>
        <li class="roundcontainer"><img src="images/image3" alt="#" /><div class="icononame">Blackmagic</div></li>
        <li class="roundcontainer"><img src="images/image4" alt="#" /><div class="icononame">Festivo</div></li>
        <li class="roundcontainer"><img src="images/image5" alt="#" /><div class="icononame">Midicon</div></li>
    </ul> 
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    height:0px;
}

.roundcontainer{
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
    margin-bottom:35px;
    margin-top:35px;
    height:190px;
    width:190px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;}

.roundcontainer img {
    height:175px;
    width:175px;
    list-style: none;
    margin:10px 10px auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
.icononame {text-align: center;
    font-family: 'minion-pro', serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    color: #323c46;
    margin-top: 9px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you share what you mean, specifically, by "lose its spacing"?

Comment: There should be padding between each list element, and for some reason that padding stops working in my widescreen unless I shrink the window. Check the bottom row how they're all aligned to the left: http://oi43.tinypic.com/i3rtif.jpg

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I could not see it before as on my machine I have only a single item on the final row. @Mr Lister's answer appears to highlight the cause of this behaviour. I have edited your question to include the screenshot you have provided :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<ul>` has inline style `text-align:justify`, and the list items are all `inline-block`s.
Effectively this means that the list items behave just like words in justified paragraphs: they get distributed evenly across the width of the ul. All except the last line of words, that is.

Solution: remove the `text-align:justify` from the `<ul>`, or change it to `text-align:center`. Then all the list items will be as close together as the last line. Add some left and right margins to the list items to space them wider apart.

Comment: So simple. I wish I could buy you a beer. You have no idea how much frustration you just relieved. It's unbelievable.

Comment: @user2680680 You're welcome. Could you mark this answer as correct? Then other people who search here will know that this problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a kind of workaround for this issue that uses several extra 'placeholder' inline-blocks of the same width. See this article: http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/